# Why is my VLC video capture output garbled?

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming

I use a video capture card, which pretends to be a webcam as a way to get video output from another system to a windows 11 tablet or  other PC. You can't fullscreen the camera app - so I was trying to run it from VLC. The video quality on windows camera is as good as I need it. VLC is not.

[image]

[image]

Graphically it defaults to potato mode *and* 4:3

VLC Settings
[image]

I've *tried* changing it to 16:9. It doesn't stick

[image]

That's the codec information from VLC

I later tried setting the display to the same resolution that the windows camera as well as the system I am capturing from is using - by putting 1920x1080 in under video size and it is still awfully antialiased and hard to read, but Marginally better

How do I set VLC to not turn my video capture into a something out of a 90s video game?
Everything else other than the capture app is the same

Comment: So what codec does is being used by the capture card?

Comment: Good question, how do I check?

Comment: Hah, setting the resolution too helps... I'm into something

Comment: Yeah. What basically happens is that there is a resolution change from BIOS to windows and VLC doesn't like it. I'm pretty sure that you only will get either the BIOS or windows displayed correctly, but not both. Maybe the capture card has a way to up-scale the BIOS and WINDOWS res to a fixed resolution and specify that in VLC?

Comment: Its comically cheap, so... probably not.